# Magento configuration version issue

Tags: magento, enterprise

I am getting this wrong version error from magento team

**Module**: community/Namespace/Module
**Location**: app/code/community/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:16
**Type**: Architecture Name: Wrong version
**Priority**: Medium
**Description**: Wrong version is defined in configuration.
**Recommendation**: Fix extension version

```
<!--Code-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>1.0.1</version><!--Line 16-->
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This is a partial code of config.xml

Comment: Please post this in Magento community forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I directly asked Magento team to answer this question, here is the reply

Version number in config.xml should be equal to current version of extension(same as mentioned in document)
And after each failure of code review version number should increase 
Example - 1.0.1 to 1.0.2

Please make sure your documentation number should match with your code otherwise your code review may fail.